# not able to download scatter plot

Tags: python

```
Collecting scatter
  Using cached scatter-0.1.3.tar.gz (3.8 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/c1/adcc6a8a9159ec24493617abb53140631509e68ebcb667f6d3ac3f1ec867/scatter-0.1.3.tar.gz#sha256=6eac39efaf07135d6f2f12d057519bc30d8df64bc6a8dfd32d19a3a99f70ad4d (from https://pypi.org/simple/scatter/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached scatter-0.1.1.tar.gz (3.8 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/d4/28c8dea108bd49847b4f1fc4fdea4f98fb1dba6420ab6676f4629d2f92d2/scatter-0.1.1.tar.gz#sha256=0677c5b889937dabf87b7f9219bfc9a983a6b1fe4663be5cc30d3ad1c7a74ff4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scatter/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scatter (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.1.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scatter
```

Comment: What is the Python version you are using?

Comment: What is the command you are executing?

Comment: What is the system you are using?

Comment: i'm using google colab

Comment: comman-pip install scatter plot

Comment: `pip install scatter plot`? Do you mean two packages `scatter` and `plot`?

Comment: no, just scatter

Comment: So, did you "Check the logs for full command output"? What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of `scatter` is from 2016, and lists Python 3.4 as most recent Python version to be supported. Python 3.4 is, however, outdated (last version 3.4.10 was released in March 2019), and thus `scatter` does not support any current Python versions. Google Colab will likely use a current Python version, and you can't install `scatter` on it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
  
x =[5, 7, 8, 7, 2, 17, 2, 9,
    4, 11, 12, 9, 6] 
  
y =[99, 86, 87, 88, 100, 86, 
    103, 87, 94, 78, 77, 85, 86]
  
plt.scatter(x, y, c ="blue")
  
# To show the plot
plt.show()
```

why you need some other scatter if the matplotlib gives the scatter plots. [image]

I think the reason of your scatter is not being installed is because it is for python  3.4